# Nav bar centering

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

Please tell me why the four nav items are not centering. I want the space between the middle two nav elements to line up with the center marking.

https://jsfiddle.net/yerc52px/

```
.mainHeader nav {
    background: #383838;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100vw;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}

.mainHeader nav ul li {display: inline;}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 18%;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background: #727272;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.mainHeader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the padding on the list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.mainHeader nav` has a width of `100vw` when you should probably be using `100%`. `100vw` wont take into account the margin being applied by the body tag, so it actually spills over 100% to be something like 100% + 20px.

https://jsfiddle.net/yerc52px/3/

```
.mainHeader nav {
    width: 100%;
```

also your `.mainHeader nav ul` has default padding being applied to it. Use this to fix that issue:

```
.mainHeader nav ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now to fix the paragraph tag... remove this:

```
p {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 10px;
}
```

and replace it with:

```
p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to remove width from your code . Edit this section.

```
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
padding: 5px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
/* width: 18%; */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/yerc52px/5/

Answer (score 0):

I'll introduce you to FLEX!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Overwrite your syntax on the following.

```
.mainHeader nav ul {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    // or if you want equal spaces between menu options
    // use justify-content:space-around
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    // Removed width
}
```

But bewary, you should always put prefix like -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, etc... But some browsers aren't supported like our favorite IE.

Here's your updated JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/yerc52px/6/